# Question about job using powershell steps then SQL DTSX File

Tags: sql, powershell, ssis

I have a simple SQL export to an XLS file. To keep the file clean, I have powershell steps:

1. Deletes the current file
2. Copies a template to the location

then runs a SQL step running a DTSX file that does a simple query and exports to the file.

when I run the DTSX file step it works fine, however after I run the two powershell steps it somehow permanently breaks the DTSX step, even if I run the job at that step only.

The only thing I can think of is I had to do set-location C: on the two powershell steps to have the code work, after i changed this the DTSX step constantly fails till I build it again, upload the new file, then it works until I run all three steps again. Any thoughts? I guess I could just build this in Visual Studio instead of using Powershell.

I tried to make the DTSX clear out the spreadsheet before it exports but that always failed, not sure if this is the way to go instead?

Step 1 (works every time):
Set-Location c:
Remove-Item -Path ""

Step 2 (works every time):
Set-Location c:
Copy-Item -Path "" -Destination ""

Step 3 (only works if I run it before ever trying the two above steps)
Type: SQL Server Integrations Service Package
Package Source: File system
I made it using a simple Export Data task.

Error after running the powershell steps, when running the DTSX step:

> Executed as user:. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility 
>   Version 11.0.6260.1 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved.     Started:  12:00:05 AM  Error: 2019-01-24
>   00:00:05.92     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: Data Flow Task 1
>   Destination - Query [32]     Description: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:
>   0x80040E37.  End Error  Error: 2019-01-24 00:00:05.92     Code:
>   0xC02020E8     Source: Data Flow Task 1 Destination - Query [32]
>   Description: Opening a rowset for "Query" failed. Check that the
>   object exists in the database.  End Error  Error: 2019-01-24
>   00:00:06.00     Code: 0xC004706B     Source: Data Flow Task 1
>   SSIS.Pipeline     Description: "Destination - Query" failed validation
>   and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".  End Error  Error:
>   2019-01-24 00:00:06.00     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data Flow Task
>   1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed
>   validation.  End Error  Error: 2019-01-24 00:00:06.00     Code:
>   0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow Task 1      Description: There were
>   errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package
>   execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  12:00:05 AM 
>   Finished: 12:00:06 AM  Elapsed:  0.812 seconds.  The package execution
>   failed.  The step failed.

Comment: Permissions maybe? I'd just have VS do the delete and copy to keep the entire thing self-contained, that's generally my approach.

Comment: The account has access to the folders and I can run them from ISE, also the job works fine after I first make it using the SQL svc account.

Comment: Any thoughts on why if I "Delete rows in destination table" is dithered? If I pick drop and recreate table it also errors.

Comment: Maybe try setting the delayvalidation property to true for the connection?

Comment: based on readings, you can't delete rows from Excel using the versions I have. the error I'm getting is this:data in a linked table is not supported by this isam

Comment: Do you need to delete the table? You said you have a template file. Delete the file using a File System task. Copy template using File System task. Then your normal Data Flow stuff. You can get fancy with expressions & variables & source/target connection properties too if you need to have specific file names.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to do with this without an SSIS task because this SQL server doesn't have SSIS enabled. I think as long as I build it in Visual Studio I can still run the DTSX file from a shared folder though. So I'm going to do it that way, I was trying to be lazy and do it without VS/SSIS haha.

Comment: Oh I see. Maybe try a batch file instead? I don't have many other ideas here. Hah